# How to get Map value with the null key inside JSP

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, el

I have a `Map<Integer, Object>` in passed to JSP from a controller. There is a null key with a default value, that means `map.get(null)` returns a default object. `keyObject.keyProp` is Integer and might be null.

When I use this in jsp

```
<c:out value="${map[keyObject.keyProp]}"/>
```

I do not get any output for the null keys. Is there any way to make null keys work in jsp?

Comment: what's `keyProp`? where is it instantiated?

Comment: btw You seem to miss **EL eval-expression**, i.e. `${expr}` or `#{expr}`. You say that you passed a _map_ to JSP from the controller (servlet). Probably you set an attribute (request or other). Then to access your map in JSP you should use Expression Language ([using scriplets is highly discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702))

Comment: Updated my answer with a simple example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the only way of getting the value for the `null` key using standard EL implementation is to **call `get()` method on the map** (considering that you said `keyObject.keyProp` resolves to *Integer* object):

```
<c:out value="${map.get(keyObject.keyProp)}" />
```

I tested this solution and it works.

Actually, in this case, you can easily do without `<c:out />`, just use plain EL where you need it, e.g.

```
${map.get(keyObject.keyProp)}
```

---

### Simple example:

*TestMapServlet.java*

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TestMapServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
        Integer noValueInt = null;
        Integer one = new Integer(1);
        Integer two = new Integer(2);

        map.put(noValueInt, "Default object for null Integer key");
        map.put(one, "Object for key = Integer(1)");
        map.put(two, "Object for key = Integer(2)");

        request.setAttribute("map", map);
        request.setAttribute("noValueInt", noValueInt);
        request.setAttribute("one", one);
        request.setAttribute("two", two);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/test-map.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

*test-map.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing access to java.util.Map using just EL</h1>
    <p><b>\${map.get(noValueInt)}</b>: ${map.get(noValueInt)}</p>
    <p><b>\${map[one]}</b>: ${map[one]}</p>
    <p><b>\${map[two]}</b>: ${map[two]}</p>

    <h1>Testing access to java.util.Map using JSTL and EL</h1>
    <p><b>&lt;c:out value="\${map.get(noValueInt)}" /&gt; </b>: <c:out value="${map.get(noValueInt)}" /></p>
    <p><b>&lt;c:out value="\${map[one]}" /&gt; </b>: <c:out value="${map[one]}" /></p>
    <p><b>&lt;c:out value="\${map[two]}" /&gt; </b>: <c:out value="${map[two]}" /></p>

    <h2>Printing java.util.Map keys and values (when Key = null, the <i>null</i> won't be shown)</h2>
    <c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
        <p><b>Key</b> = "${entry.key}", <b>Value</b> = "${entry.value}"</p>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test Map Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.TestMapServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test Map Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/TestMap.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
To be able to invoke methods with arguments using EL you must use minimum *Servlet version 3.0*.
Quote from here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

> Since EL 2.2, which is maintained as part of Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2
>   (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc), it's possible to invoke
>   non-getter methods, if necessary with arguments.

---

Apart from the above solution you could use **custom Unified Expression Language implementation** such as [**JUEL**](http://juel.sourceforge.net/index.html) that has an alternative solution.

An **explanation why** it is not possible (in the standard implementation) to access *map* value by the `null` *key* using `[]` and the custom solution can be found in [**Java Unified Expression Language (JUEL) documentation**](http://juel.sourceforge.net/juel.pdf) (emphasis in paragraphs is mine):

> ### **2.5. Advanced Topics**
>
> ...
>
> #### Enabling/Disabling null
>   Properties
>
> The EL specification describes the evaluation
>   semantics of `base[property]`. If property is null, the specification
>   states not to resolve null on base. Rather, null should be returned if
>   `getValue(...)` has been called and a `PropertyNotFoundException` should
>   be thrown else. As a consequence, it is impossible to resolve null as
>   a key in a map. However, **JUEL's expression factory may be configured
>   to resolve null like any other property value**. To enable (disable)
>   null as an EL property value, you may set property
>   `javax.el.nullProperties` to true (false).
>
> Assume that identifier map resolves to a `java.util.Map`.
>
> - If feature `javax.el.nullProperties` has
>     been disabled, evaluating `${base[null]}` as an rvalue (lvalue) will
>     return null (throw an exception).
> - **If feature `javax.el.nullProperties`
>     has been enabled**, evaluating `${base[null]}` as an rvalue (lvalue) will
>     get (put) the value for key null in that map. The default is not to
>     allow null as an EL property value.
>
> ...

Hope this will help.